# Error Generating Fixtures. Rails was not able to disable referential integrity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, testing, fixtures

I understand that rails is supposed to disable referential integrity when generating the fixtures. So after a quick Google search, i figured out that the solution to the error following error is to make my postgres user a super user. The error:

```
WARNING: Rails was not able to disable referential integrity.:00,  ETA: 00:00:00

This is most likely caused due to missing permissions.
Rails needs superuser privileges to disable referential integrity.

ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:         ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "responses" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_2ec3339f90"
    DETAIL:  Key (assessment_id)=(1) is not present in table "assessments".
    : INSERT INTO "joe"."responses" ("assessment_id", "user_id", "question_id", "choice_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, '2017-05-08', '2017-05-08')
```

I thought it would be an easy fix, but my postgres user is already a superuser. I did `SHOW is_superuser;` and the response was `on`. I even disabled all of the triggers manually from the command line with the same user using `alter table responses disable trigger all;`. When I list the postgres users using `\du`, the attributes show up as `Superuser, Create role, Create DB`.

I am very confident that my user is a superuser. There must be something else going on here. I am using the apartment gem for multi-tenancy. Help is appreciated. If you need any more code, let me know.

Comment: Did you fix this? What's in your database.yml file?

Comment: I did get past this, but this occurred a while ago so I don't completely remember how. I may have recreated my database.

Answer (score 0):

The user specified in `config/database.yml` - say `rails_deploy_user` needs to have superuser privileges defined, not the generic postgres user.

```
psql database_environment
\du;  # find psql defined users and roles
ALTER ROLE rails_deploy_user WITH SUPERUSER;
```